# Cancelling TextChanged events (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a bit of an issue with something I'm working on in ASP.NET/C#. I am using a GridView to display all 'items' linked to an account, with 3 fields relating to the link, but also all files not linked to it. Next to all records is a checkbox so they can link/unlink the two, and modify the 3 fields relating to that link.

I am currently using the 'CheckedChanged' and 'TextChanged' events to update the entries, as opposed to looping through each row in the Grid, checking its current state and updating accordingly etc which would provide a lot of overhead.

Problem is,the events fire if the user clicks a 'Cancel' button. Is there a way to detect if this certain button has been Clicked, and stop the events from firing? Or do you guys have better ideas?

Comment: what the Cancel should be doing?

Comment: Sorry, foolish of me not to state. The whole Grid is in a modalpopupextender, so the cancel button hides the modalpopupextender, and ideally flushes out any changes on the grid that were not saved due to validation

Comment: so why not having pure client side on the button click? Can't see any reason to trigger PostBack just to hide the popup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it sounds like your Cancel button's Clicked handler is assigned to your custom function somewhere. By default it shouldn't do anything.

However, you can use the Sender object to check the type of object that fired the event:

```
if (sender is Checkbox) {
    // Do something useful
}
```

*I have not tested this code.*

Comment: sender  is alwasy a textbox, which fired event.